# content css ignored after setData in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, drupal, ckeditor

I get the text and add some classes to spans.  setData updates the content but the content css is not applied.

I can inspect(in Chrome) and see the new classes.  I toggle on a Drupal page between flat text and WYSIWYG(disable-enable rich text) and it looks fine.

it is as if the editor forgets or stops applying  the content css on setData

I tried:

```js
function submitaftersetdata() {
    this.updateElement();
 this.checkdirty;
 CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss =  'http://www.mooyai.com/sites/all/modules/custom/languagetool/atd-ckeditor/atd.css';
 alert('done');
}

 editor.setData(editorContents, submitaftersetdata);
```

```js
editor.insertHtml(editorContents);
```

works fine to add the new text and looks correct(the content css is applied)

setData to empty '' then insert works but again breaks the css

Answer (score 0):

I found a weak work around:

```html
editor.execCommand( 'selectAll' );
editor.insertHtml(editorContents);
```